# How to pre-fill RsForm with URL parameters

Tags: joomla-2.5, url, rsform

I followed [this guide](http://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/view-article/162-how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-through-the-url-and-how-can-i-catch-it-.html) on how to pass a parameter through the URL in RsForm,
and with it I tried to define default value of one box. Even though I followed that tutorial, my browser accepts the url but doesn't fill out the field.

```
example.com/cs?option=com_rsform&formId=13form[vyberte_vami_zvoleny_pobyt]=name@example.com
```

(BTW, the first box should get the parameter `name@example.com`)

Comment: You're missing an ampersand (&) in the url currently: `example.com/cs?option=com_rsform&formId=13&form[vyberte_vami_zvoleny_pobyt]=name@example.com`. Are you sure that this all matches exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is wrong, it should only contain one question mark (`?option=com_rsform`). Subsequent URL parameters must start with `&`.

Try http://www.trebonlazne.cz/cs?option=com_rsform&formId=13&form[vyberte_vami_zvoleny_pobyt]=mail@domain.com, it should work.

From the [tutorial](http://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/view-article/162-how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-through-the-url-and-how-can-i-catch-it-.html) you mentioned:

> IMPORTANT: If the parameter you are adding is the first one existing
>   in the URL (when using SEF URLs), you need to add it using the ?
>   character instead of &, as in the following example: 
>   http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php/form?form[email]=mail@domain.com

Answer (score 1):

This is an example I have used for a hotel booking engine

```
example.com/page.jsp?HotelID={HotelID:value}&rateplanid={rateplan:value}&Rooms=1&DateIn={Check In:value}&Length={Nights:value}&Adults={Adults:value}&Children={Children:value}&submit=Submit
```

In this case, we use {} instead of [].